# Bootstrap 4, I can't get my fixed navbar to be separate from my jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm creating a website, and am using Bootstrap. I want my fixed navbar to be separate from my jumbotron, but I can't seem to get them to separate.

Is there any way to do this without directly editing the CSS file?

This is an example of how my jumbotron is bound to the navbar:

[image: This is an example of how my jumbotron is bound to the navbar]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you with CSS, you will need to provide both your CSS and your HTML; we can't reproduce your problem without it. Please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is add another class to the jumbotron so add something like `topmargin` then in your css styles add `margin-top: 10px` or however much space you need.. the best way to add spaces in your project is to set up a spacer div so you can have the same space between every element on your page so doing something like `<div class="spacer"></div>` and in your styles

```
.spacer{
    height: 10px //however much space you want between elements
    content: "";
}
```

then whenever you need spaces inbetween elements you can just chuck in the spacer div

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding-top to your body

```
body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

Without editing css file.

You could you jQuery

```
$('body').css('padding-top', 70px);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding margin to your jumbotron. You can do this with the included spacing classes in Bootstrap.

Try `mt-5` (margin top), and use a lower number if you want less margin.

You can also use padding in this way. In that case you'll use something like `pt-5`.